# how to update object attributes with json path entries

Tags: java

Anybody knows a way to update an object (POJO) with json-path entries?

My sample POJO:

```
class Book (
  String isbn;
  Author author;
  String title;
)
class Author (
  String firsName;
  String lastName;
)
```

JSON-Path entries:

```
author.firstName="John"
title="Unknown"
```

In result a specific book object should be updated with values from Json-Path entries.
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Can you update your question?  `author.firstName="John"` isn't JSON Path, and I'm not sure what you mean by "JSON Path entry."  JSON Path is a query syntax for JSON data.  It doesn't support mutations or transformations.

Comment: Yes - it's not pure JSON Path - it's a convention path to locate fields to be updated.
Some difficulty might be with maps :(

Comment: Alright.  I'm going to remove the `jsonpath` tag since it's not related.